# "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am new in QA and i tried to automate for the first time in **Microsoft Edge Version 109.0.1518.61** and getting these errors: [These are the error i am getting first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpzef.jpg)[2nd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MInf3.jpg)

- SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
- SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
- SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I am using this as a maven project. There is no error in the code blocks.My whole code block is given below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;

public class BrowserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
        options.addArguments("edge.switches","--disable-extensions");
        WebDriver Driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
        
        Driver.get("https://seleniumhq.org/");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your below line:

```
Driver.get("https://seleniumhq.org/");
```

This happens when the URL you are trying to hit is not reachable, URL is blocked by a proxy etc. If you are not specific about using this URL, then try the below code:

```
Driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/");
```

On another note, as a best practice follow java standard naming conventions. For example variable name **Driver** should be **driver**

Comment: `org` vs `dev` great observation +1